# Is there a shorthand property for positioning?

Tags: css, css-position, shorthand

Similer to how you can write:

```
margin: 12px 8px 10px 8px;
//or
padding: 12px 8px 10px 8px;
```

is there a way to shorthand position properties?

```
//from    
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;

//to
position: absolute 0 0 0 0;
```

or something?

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) doesn't seem to have anything, but it could be called something else or a different method entirely.

Comment: Nope... Sorry... probably in a future spec. Maybe you can make a mixin with scss.

Answer (score 1):

***No you can't shorthand `position`*** with other properties like `top` as they're separate properties entirely, unlike `background` with image and color for example. If you want to save on writing CSS, you could check out mixins in CSS preprocessors like Sass and LESS.

An example mixin in Sass:

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
     -moz-border-radius: $radius;
      -ms-border-radius: $radius;
          border-radius: $radius;
}

.box { @include border-radius(10px); }
```

The above is taken from the Sass [Mixin Reference](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6).

Obviously if you don't want to use a preprocessor, you'll just need to manually write it out every time you want to use those properties.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

Here is the current definition of the CSS Positioning Module Level 3: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/ - the document does not define any shorthand form for `position` and `left`, `right`, `top`, or `down`.